# How to click on the thumb and the video appear AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image: This is my Responsive YouTube Player with Scrolling Thumbnail Playlist]

Here´s my code

```
<div class="container">
            <!-- THE YOUTUBE PLAYER -->
            <div class="vid-container">
                <iframe id="vid_frame" ng-src="{{selectedVideo.url}}" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
            </div>


            <!-- THE PLAYLIST -->
            <div class="vid-list-container">
                <div class="vid-list">

                    <div ng-repeat="video in youTubeVideos">
                        <div class="vid-item" ng-click="selectedVideo.url = video.url">
                            <div class="thumb"><img ng-src="//img.youtube.com/vi/{{video.img}}/0.jpg"></div>
                            <div class="desc">{{video.desc}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

$scope.youTubeVideos = [
                {
                    url: '//youtube.com/embed/eg6kNoJmzkY?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1',
                    img: 'eg6kNoJmzkY',
                    desc: 'Jessica Hernandez & the Deltas - Dead Brains'
                },
                {
                    url: '//youtube.com/embed/_Tz7KROhuAw?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1',
                    img: '_Tz7KROhuAw',
                    desc: 'Barbatuques - CD Tum P&aacute; - Sambalel&ecirc;'
                },
            ];

            $scope.selectedVideo = {};
```

There is an error on Console:
**Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{selectedVideo.url}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: https://youtube.com/embed/eg6kNoJmzkY**

I can not solve this error and I also need to leave video # 1 available in vid-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You resource request is being blocked by the `$sceDelegateProvider` in AngularJS.

> The $sceDelegateProvider allows one to get/set the whitelists and
>   blacklists used to ensure that the URLs used for sourcing AngularJS
>   templates and other script-running URLs are safe

Add the URL to the `$sceDelegateProvider` whitelist and you should be able to grab the video

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        'https://youtube.com/embed/**'
    ]);
});
```

---

**How can I change the selected video?**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('videoCntrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.changeVideo = function (video) {
        $scope.selectedVideo = $scope.videos[video];
    }

    $scope.videos = [{
        url: '//youtube.com/embed/eg6kNoJmzkY?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1',
        img: 'eg6kNoJmzkY',
        desc: 'Jessica Hernandez & the Deltas - Dead Brains'
    },
    {
        url: '//youtube.com/embed/_Tz7KROhuAw?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1',
        img: '_Tz7KROhuAw',
        desc: 'Barbatuques - CD Tum P&aacute; - Sambalel&ecirc;'
    }];

}]);
```

Add the `ng-click` attribute to your desired trigger. Something like:

```
<div ng-click="changeVideo(1)"></div>
```

Finally, add the `ng-controller` attribute on the body tag.

```
<body ng-controller="videoCntrl">
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It works!! Awesome dude! Do you know how can I put the first video in vid-container when I reload the page?